# Button with correct signature not found in type

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-button

I keep getting this "correct signature not found in type error" when adding a button. I've tried every variation of the signature that I can think of to no avail. I think the issue may have something to do with the other errors. Do the errors come from using Drive to store the files? [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDJCu.png) [Code behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6zXe.png) [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPidm.png)

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: Could you provide more details for us to reproduce?

Comment: Are you guys unable to see the code snippets?

Comment: Add try-catch so you can find out where is issue and send that Exception so we will identify what is problem. Also, you can debug code so you have a clear idea of which line error is occure.

Comment: I checked the code. It works well for me. I guess the `OnQuoteButtonClick` event does not register in Xaml. Right the `OnQuoteButtonClick` in your xaml and right click to select `Peek Definition`.